# Comparing mean ratings of images that have different number of ratings

Tags: mean, dataset

I have 20 000 images each with an average rating between 0-7, the number of people who have rated that image, and the standard deviation (I also have the distribution of the ratings, but I'm not sure if that is relevant).
For example,

> Image1:  No. ratings: 18; Mean: 5.17; Std Dev.: 0.583333333333339
>
> Image2:  No. ratings: 11; Mean: 5.36; Std Dev: 1.32231404958678

Now in order to find the image with the highest rating, I would initially think of taking the one with the higher mean rating. However, since the one with the higher rating had less people to decide that rating, I want a way to normalize the values in order to compare.

Is there a way for me to accurately compare all 20 000 images in the dataset and find the top 10 highest rated ones (despite the difference in the number of ratings the images have received)?